# Calculating a double infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to calculate these double infinite series

$$\sum_{m = -\infty}^\infty \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{x + m}{\left(\left(x + m\right)^2 + \left(y + n\right)^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}$$
and
$$\sum_{m = -\infty}^\infty \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{y + n}{\left(\left(x + m\right)^2 + \left(y + n\right)^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}$$

, which is needed for calculating force on a planer torus. I think it's a bit similar with
calculating madelung constant, but it is about force while madelung constant is about energy.

If it's not possible to get exact value, is there any efficient approximation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the double sums both diverge.

Comment: @GEdgar  Oh, really? Doesn't it even conditionally converge? I thought it would converge because the expression in the sum looks like about inverse of square. Adding it 
with python looks converging too...

Comment: $\sum 1/n^a$ converges for $a>1$ in one dimension. But here is two dimensions, and $\sum\sum 1/\|x\|^a$ summed over the $2$-d lattice converges for $a>2$.  For "conditional convergence" you should specify the mode of convergence you want.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for your comment! I think I should think about it more...